# I cannot fetch data from my own json file in Nestjs

Tags: json, axios, nestjs

I would like to read data from my own json file and return it to my Nestjs controller but unable to read the url

My db.json is stored in the root folder

The error I am getting is

> this.httpService.get is not a function

My service

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common'
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios'
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'
import { AxiosResponse } from 'axios'

import { Data } from './resource.schema'

@Injectable()
export class ResourcesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel('Resources')
    private httpService: HttpService,
  ) {}

  getAll(): Observable<AxiosResponse<Data>> {
    return this.httpService.get('http://localhost:5000/api/v1/db.json')
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common'

import { ResourcesService } from './resources.service'

@Controller('resources')
export class ResourcesController {
  constructor(private readonly resourcesService: ResourcesService) {}

  @Get('all')
  getAll() {
    return this.resourcesService.getAll()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@InjectModel()` is acting upon the `httpServcie` constructor parameter, so Nest is injecting `getModelToken('Resources')` instead of the `httpService`, meaning the `get` isn't what Typescript thinks it is. MOst likely, you're meaning to have `@InjectModel('Resources') private readonly resourcesModel: MNOdel<Resources>` in the constructor *along with* the `private readonly httpService: HttpService` so that you have two injected valujes, not one.